# How can I gain root access and use disk usage (du) from electron's main process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, unix, electron

I'm building a macOS app using [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)

I try to run the following command from the main process using `ipcMain` and NodeJS's `exec`.

```
// Traverse to a directory and use disk usage to check folder sizes
cd ~/Library/Caches && du -sh *
```

The command gets executed the way I want it too but it throws an exception.

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Command failed: cd ~/Library/Caches && du -sh *
du: DEDUCTED: Operation not permitted

    at /Users/0x1ad2/Projects/DEDUCTED/node_modules/sudo-prompt/index.js:390:27
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:61:3)
```

I also tried to attach the package [sudo-prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo-prompt) so the application can have root access.

No luck so far.

**Answer**

```
    const exec = require("child_process").exec;
exec(
    `cd ~/Library/Caches && du -sh * && cd ${process.cwd()}`,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in `cd`. Module `sudo-prompt` [redirect stderror to file](https://github.com/jorangreef/sudo-prompt/blob/master/index.js#L653). Just try to run like this example or add command for return back like `cd ~/Library/Caches && du -sh * && cd ${process.cwd()}`

```
child_process.exec('push /etc\ndu -sh *\npopd', (error, stdout, stderr)=> console.log(stdout))
```

`

Comment: It's indeed the `cd` thanks for pointing that out. But still, if I let the process return via `cd ${process.cwd()}` it still throws the same exception.

Comment: Commands like `ls`, `mkdr`, `cd` and `touch` do work. But whenever I add `du` things break.

Comment: I mean cod like `child_process.exec(`cd ~/Library/Caches && du -sh * && cd ${process.cwd()`, (error, stdout, stderr)=> console.log(stdout))`